# Handling mouse events on a QQuickItem

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qtquick2

I have created a basic QML application which uses QQuickView for creating a view, and has custom QQuickItems in it. I want to handle mouse events on one such QQuickItem by reimplementing the *mousepressevent*(QEvent *) method. **However, when I run the application and click on the QQuickItem, no call is made to** *mousepressevent*(QEvent *) **method.**

The header file of the QQuickItem looks like this:

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QSGGeometry>
#include <QSGFlatColorMaterial>

class TriangularGeometry: public QQuickItem
{
         Q_OBJECT
         public:
              TriangularGeometry(QQuickItem* parent = 0);
              QSGNode* updatePaintNode(QSGNode*, UpdatePaintNodeData*);
              void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

         private:
              QSGGeometry m_geometry;
              QSGFlatColorMaterial m_material;
              QColor m_color;
};
```

Note: I am making use of scenegraph to render the QuickItem.

This is a snippet from the cpp file:

```
void TriangularGeometry::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_color = Qt::black;
    update(); //changing an attribute of the qquickitem and updating the scenegraph
}
```

I can handle mouse events from the application but, as per my requirements, I need to handle it by overriding the method *mousePressEvent*(QMouseEvent *event).

Comment: Got the solution. Have to call setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons) first (in the constructor). Any click on the QuickItem routes the mouse event handling to mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) function.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to use mouse directly in item, you have MouseArea for that. "Single Responsibility Principle" : do one thing, but doing well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure, you have called this method before handling events (constructor is a good place):

`setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);`

Buttons enum of course can be any what you want.

Comment: This worked for me for `mousePressEvent`, but it doesn't work for `mouseReleaseEvent`, which is fired only after a `mouseDoubleClickEvent`. Is it only me?

Comment: Just for users that try to solve this problem too. Don't call base method mousePressEvent and other methods. It's because QQuickItem call ignore event and thats why you can't handle Release event